# Making a simple chase AI in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

im attempting to make a simple game where zombies spawn out randomly from the edges of the screen and once they have spawned, they will get the last position of the player and keep moving towards that direction until they hit the stage and gets removed. However, i seem to be having a problem with the chase code. Even after reading tons of articles that offer the same chunk of code, im still unable to make it work (IM DOING IT WRONG ARRGH).

This is the main class

```
package 
{
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.utils.*;
import flash.ui.*;

public class main extends MovieClip
{
    private var left,right,up,down,fire,mouseRight,mouseLeft:Boolean;
    private var speedX,speedY,mobPosX,mobPosY:int;
    private var num:Number;
    private var wizard:Player;
    private var crosshair:Crosshair;
    private var mobArray,magicArray:Array;

    public function main()
    {
        //Hide mouse for crosshair
        Mouse.hide();
        crosshair = new Crosshair();
        addChild(crosshair);
        crosshair.x = stage.stageWidth;
        crosshair.y = stage.stageHeight;

        //Set initial speed
        speedX = 0;
        speedY = 0;

        //Wizard stuff
        fire = false;
        wizard = new Player();
        addChild(wizard);
        wizard.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
        wizard.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;

        //Mob stuff
        mobArray = new Array();
        magicArray = new Array();


        //Initialize bool so movement doesn't get stuck on startup
        up = false;
        down = false;
        left = false;
        right = false;

    }

    public function startGame()
    {



        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyDownHandler);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,keyUpHandler);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myClick);


    }

    private function keyDownHandler(evt:KeyboardEvent)
    {

        if (evt.keyCode == 37)
        {
            left = true;
        }

        if (evt.keyCode == 38)
        {
            up = true;

        }

        if (evt.keyCode == 39)
        {
            right = true;
        }

        if (evt.keyCode == 40)
        {
            down = true;
        }

        if (evt.keyCode == 67)
        {
            trace(mobArray.length);
        }

    }

    private function keyUpHandler(evt:KeyboardEvent)
    {
        if (evt.keyCode == 37)
        {
            left = false;
            speedX = 0;
        }

        if (evt.keyCode == 38)
        {
            up = false;
            speedY = 0;
        }

        if (evt.keyCode == 39)
        {
            right = false;
            speedX = 0;
        }

        if (evt.keyCode == 40)
        {
            down = false;
            speedY = 0;
        }

    }

    function myClick(eventObject:MouseEvent)
    {
        fire = true;
    }


    public function update(evt:Event)
    {
        //UI
        crosshair.x = mouseX;
        crosshair.y = mouseY;

        //Start player
        if (left && right == false)
        {
            speedX = -8;
        }

        if (up && down == false)
        {
            speedY = -8;
        }

        if (down && up == false)
        {
            speedY = 8;
        }

        if (right && left == false)
        {
            speedX = 8;
        }

        wizard.x +=  speedX;
        wizard.y +=  speedY;

        for (var i = mobArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            //Start mob                                 //if X is zero and Y > 10, spawn.

            var m:Zombie = new Zombie();
            m.chase((Math.atan2(mobArray[i].y - wizard.y,mobArray[i].x - wizard.x)/Math.PI * 180)); //applies trigo
            num = Math.random();
            if (num < 0.1)
            {
                //when x = 0
                mobPosX = 10;
                mobPosY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 590) + 10;
            }
            else if (num < 0.3)
            {
                //when y = 0
                mobPosX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 790) + 10;
                mobPosY = 10;
            }
            else if (num < 0.6)
            {
                mobPosX = 800;
                mobPosY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 590) + 10;
                //when x width of screen
            }
            else if (num < 0.9)
            {
                //y is height of screen
                mobPosX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 790) + 10;
                mobPosY = 590;
            }
            m.x = mobPosX;
            m.y = mobPosY;
            mobArray.push(m);
            addChild(m);
        }




    }

    private function gameOver()
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
        stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyDownHandler);
        stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,keyUpHandler);
    }



}//end class
 }//end package
```

This is the zombie class

```
package 
  {
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;

public class Zombie extends MovieClip
{
    private var zombSpd:Number;
    private var angle:Number;

    public function Zombie()
    {
        zombSpd = 10;
    }

    public function chase(chaseAngle:Number)
    {
        angle = chaseAngle;
    }


    public function update()
    {
        this.x+=Math.cos(angle*Math.PI/180)*zombSpd;
        this.y+=Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/180)*zombSpd;
    }


}//end class
   }//end package
```

Thank you :)

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does the Zombie not go in the right direction?

Comment: What actually happens? What do you expect should happen?

Comment: You're spawning more and more zombies every frame tick, which doesn't seem right.. Also it's generally not a good idea to modify an array while looping through it.

Comment: @MartyWallace The zombies aren't spawning once i add the forloop and they aren't chasing the player's last position.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Im expecting the zombies to spawn at the edges of the game window and chase the player based on the last position wizard was at. (Think of it as a cannon with a mouseclick, the cannon's bullet will follow the mouseclick's last coordinate but it won't follow the mouse and will go all the way to the edge of the screen).

Comment: @WillKru Hi, how do you propose i rectify the problem? Thank you!

Comment: Create your zombies and push them to the array at initialization, then during the game, loop through the array updating your zombies. If you need to remove zombies from the array, push them to a second array and loop through that one after you're done with the first loop. The problem when modifying an array while iterating it is that the items will get reindexed and there's a chance you will skip items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just reread your code and see that you must read and learn more about programming before trying to create a game like this.

the reason your zombies are not spawning are because you never get inside the for loop.  mob array length will be zero to start with, so the for loop will never happen.

take that for loop out and create a function to spawn enemies in your main class.  you can use the code you use in your for loop as the code for this function example:

```
function spawn():void{
    //code directly from your for loop, with a small change            
        num = Math.random();
        if (num < 0.1)
        {
            //when x = 0
            mobPosX = 10;
            mobPosY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 590) + 10;
        }
        else if (num < 0.3)
        {
            //when y = 0
            mobPosX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 790) + 10;
            mobPosY = 10;
        }
        else if (num < 0.6)
        {
            mobPosX = 800;
            mobPosY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 590) + 10;
            //when x width of screen
        }
        else if (num < 0.9)
        {
            //y is height of screen
            mobPosX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 790) + 10;
            mobPosY = 590;
        }
        var m:Zombie = new Zombie();
        m.x = mobPosX;
        m.y = mobPosY;
        m.chase((Math.atan2(m.y - wizard.y,m.x - wizard.x)/Math.PI * 180)); //applies trigo
        mobArray.push(m);
        addChild(m);
}
```

now in your update function you must determine when you want enemies to spawn.  you can do this by using a counter.  Ill let you figure that part out, but if you want zombies to spawn continuously, (where your forloop in the update function was) add this:

```
//use a counter variable to determine when to execute spawn
spawn();
//loop through all zombies
for(var i:int = 0; i < mobArray.length; i++){
    mobArray[i].update();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer @Travis, 

Im quite confused by this actually, am i supposed to use:

`m.chase(mathAtan2stuff);
m.update();`

or

`mobArray[i].chase("Math atan2 stuff, which you seem to be doing right");
mobArray[i].update();`

Comment: you need more practice with as3 and programming, I updated my answer to solve most of the problems I saw when I reread.

Answer (score -1):

Steering behavior example at AdvanceEDActionScriptAnimation with abstracted interfaces and marshaling implementation.
Github:https://github.com/yangboz/as3SteeringBehavior